# Can I be charged for letting a domain expire?

Tags: legal, money, international

A few months ago I let a domain expire that I no longer wanted.  I just received a bill from a collections agency saying that I owe about $100 because although I let the domain expire, it's necessary to cancel it as well.

The domain in question is a ".at" Austrian.

I've never needed to cancel a domain before - letting it expire was enough. This was my first Austrian domain name, and I'd appreciate any insight the community might have.

Comment: Did the bill start with "Please allow me to introduce myself. My name is Dr. (Mrs.) Mariam Abacha, the wife of the late head of state and commander"?

Comment: I've had a similar experience with UK2.NET, who insist on charging for a cancelled site. I cancelled the card they were using, disputed the payment and told them where to go...

Comment: I almost threw the bill away because I'm used to those kind of junk mailings. This one looked a bit different and was from a legitimate Austrian collections agency. Unfortunately it looks like NIC.at does require domain cancellation in addition to expiration. Just a word of warning for others that buy .at domains.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you had a pre-existing contract with them that required you to renew the domain or notify them of cancellation, then they cannot charge you.

[AT domain registration](http://www.nic.at/en/service/legal_information/terms_conditions/)

So basically, it depends on whether or not there were explicit terms from your registrar about this occurring; which if there are, you should be able to find them on your registrar's site.

Comment: I would insist that they should you where you agreed to that in the original contract.

Comment: The registrar I used (joker.com) did in fact tell me about needing to explicitly cancel the domain at the time of registration and provided warnings before the domain expired. Of course like other domain expiration notices I just ignored them. I won't do that anymore. Luckily I was able to make a compromise with the collections agency for about $65 US.

Comment: Ahh, that's a shame. But well done with the reduction!